# Karma/Jasmine angular spyOn returns always the value from stub class

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I`m having difficulty mocking my async service function.
The stub class is:

```
export class AdminServiceStub {
    getArchivedOrdersByPage(query: string): Observable<{ orders: IOrder[], count: number }> {
        return of({
            orders: [{
                _id: '123',
                completed: true,
                createdAt: '123',
                deliveryPrice: 1099,
                isVisible: false,
                status: 'completed',
                totalPrice: 1099,
                guest: {
                    firstName: 'John',
                    lastName: 'Doe'
                },
                products: [
                    {
                        _id: '123',
                        onModel: 'Notebook',
                        product: {
                            _id: '123',
                            brand: 'Lenovo',
                            model: 'Yoga',
                            images: ['']
                        },
                        purchasePrice: 1099,
                        purchaseQuantity: 1,
                        type: 'notebooks'
                    }
                ]
            }],
            count: 2
        })
    }
}
```

I provide the fake service:

```
 providers: [
        {
          provide: AdminService,
          useClass: AdminServiceStub
        },
```

In test i'm trying to return observable with different values, but instead i'm always getting the value from stub class:

```
it('should show no orders message', async () => {
    const adminService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AdminService);
    const spy = spyOn(adminService, 'getArchivedOrdersByPage').and.returnValue(
      of({
        orders: [],
        count: 0
      }));
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      let result = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.order').textContent;
      expect(result).toContain('No orders for selected period.');
    });
  });
```

Can you help me to return different values from the fake service class.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
describe('Your Service Name', () => {
let adminService: AdminService; <== add this line
....
....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({  
   .....
   .....
   providers: [
       {
          provide: AdminService,
          useClass: AdminServiceStub
       }
   ]
}).compileComponents();

adminService = TestBed.get(AdminService);
})


.
.
.
. 
// In your test case now: 
// Try without doing the .whenStable()
it('should show no orders message', async () => {
    spyOn(adminService, 'getArchivedOrdersByPage').and.returnValue(
      of({
        orders: [],
        count: 0
      }));
      let result = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.order').textContent;
      expect(result).toContain('No orders for selected period.');
});

// If the above test case doesn't work, 
a) If your testing your service method in your component, then do this: 

it('should run the #componentMethod()', () => {
   spyOn(component, 'componentMethod').and.callThrough(); 
   spyOn(adminService, 'getArchivedOrdersByPage').and.returnValue(
      of({
        orders: [],
        count: 0
        })
   );
   component.componentMethod();
   expect(component.componentMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
}); 

b) If your testing your service method in your service spec file, then do this: 

it('should run the #serviceMethod()', () => {
   spyOn(adminService, 'getArchivedOrdersByPage').and.returnValue(
      of({
        orders: [],
        count: 0
        })
   );
   service.serviceMethod();
   expect(service.serviceMethod).toBeDefined();
});
```

Either of the methods should work..You can try them.